# Location : Proximity Search Slider Instead of Number Field

Tags: views

I'm currently trying to use the [Select with Style](https://drupal.org/project/select_with_style) module to set a distance from a location using the Proximity Distance feature of the [Location](https://drupal.org/project/location) Module.

I want to be able to use a slider to select the distance from a point rather than use the number input field provided by default.

Comment: Is proximity search done directly or via views?

Comment: Its used as a filter in views.